# Which property indicates the published status of a modern page?

Tags: publishing-page, modern-pages, communication-site

I've been under the impression that modern pages use the ows__ModerationStatus indicate whether or not the page is published - just like with classic publishing pages. Last week, I tried to map this crawled property to a RefinableString*** to make it available for the Search index. One week later this managed property still contains no values. With PowerShell I can verify that those modern pages' internal field contains a value indicating the published state and that they also change based on when I publish a modern page in the browser.

a) I can't figure out why the managed property doesn't get populated with values from modern pages. It does from classic publishing pages, though

b) is there another property at play here indicating the published state for a modern page, e.g. from a communication site?

Thanks for your help.